# Combine two numbers in excel while making sure the second has two digits

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, zero

I have a formula that takes part of a number and transforms it before stitching the number back together:

```
B1=RIGHT(A1;2)*0.2
=LEFT(A1;LEN(A1)-2)&B1
```

Values of B1 are expected to be one or two digits long and represent part of a time code.

The trouble is that if B1 is a single digit number the time code is wrong.

Ex:

```
A1=14345
B1=9

Result: 1439
Desired Result: 14309 (1:43:09)
```

I really want to avoid using

```
=IF((RIGHT(A1;2)*0.2)<10;0&RIGHT(A1;2)*0.2;RIGHT(A1;2)*0.2)
```

because in reality the formula can become considerably more complex and having recurring elements in it significantly reduces my ability to read and troubleshoot it.

In short, can I use some function to make sure a number is always two digits long even when the first one is zero when when concatenating two numbers.

Many thanks,
Johnson

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you elaborate what your end-goal is here. You mentioned a more complex formula which sparks some interest. Just to prevent an XY-problem here, are you sure you need to use all these steps to get where you want to end up?

Comment: @JvdV Hey, thanks for asking, I'm trying to work out a robust algorithm for converting time codes from hh:mm:ss:ms (the last is two digit millisecond timing, only includes hundreds and tens) to hh:mm:ss:ff (two digit frames of a given base frame rate. So far I've been able to do it with 24fps with some rounding, but it's still quit cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`TEXT()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) to format the single digit into two digits.

```
=TEXT(9,"00")
```

In your case this could look like:

```
=TEXT(RIGHT(A1,2)*0.2,"00")
```

Or as a whole:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&TEXT(RIGHT(A1,2)*0.2,"00")
```

Comment: Great stuff my man! Thanks, now I can simply slap a NUMBERVALUE() to the front of that and it's perfect for what I need!

Comment: No need for `NUMBERVALUE()`. You could use `--` or multiply by 1 if you are interested in "Code Golf". Either way. Have you seen my comment under your question?